# resolution conflict in magento extensions

Tags: module, magento-1

I have two modules.

```
<sales>
   <rewrite>
       <order>Extension_A_Model_Sales_Order</order>
   </rewrite>
</sales>
```

```
<sales>
   <rewrite>
       <order>Extension_B_Model_Sales_Order</order>
   </rewrite>
</sales>
```

I found the following way to fix conflict in them:

```
<config>
 <modules>
   <Extension_B>
      <depends>
          <Extension_A/>
      </depends>
   </Extension_B>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Then

I need to use `<depends>`, what else shall I do to complete this task? Do I need to remove  when using  to fix conflict.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Same model rewrite in two modules causes conflict?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40206/same-model-rewrite-in-two-modules-causes-conflict/40208#40208)

update your class

```
class Extension_A_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Model_Sales_Order

class Extension_B_Model_Sales_Order extends Extension_A_Model_Sales_Order
```

Then remove

```
<sales>
   <rewrite>
       <order>Extension_A_Model_Sales_Order</order>
   </rewrite>
</sales>
```