# Load Checkout comments in sales/order/print - basic module question

Tags: checkout, module, magento-1, onestepcheckout

**Short version**: my question is how do I load all my checkout data in that pdf generator so that I can run functions like `$order->getOnestepcheckoutCustomercomment()`

**Long version**: I'm writing a module to insert One step checkout comments in sales/order/print (on success page, the print order pdf generator).

I've done it for the admin pdf generator and it works fine there by using

```
<models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>                    
                    <order_pdf_invoice>Company_Module_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
</models>
```

and the `Invoice.php` in the relevant directory structure:

```
class Company_Invoices_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Webshopapps_Invoicing_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice{
//checkout functions here
}
```

Now I've been trying like this:

```
<helpers>
      <invoices>
          <class>Company_Invoices_Helper</class>
      </invoices>
    </helpers>
```

and in Data.php:

```
class Company_Invoices_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
if( !$order->getOnestepcheckoutCustomercomment() ) { return; }

        $this->y -= 5;

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));

        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));

        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);

 //etc.  all the checkout functions

}
```

Here I have to run some functions like the ones above, but I get the error `"getOnestepcheckoutCustomercomment() call to a non object"` so I'm guessing that I have to load all the checkout data and i'm unsure how.

In `sales/order/print` I am calling it like this `<?php $helper = Mage::helper('invoices'); ?>`

So, my question is how do I load OSC data in sales/order/print

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of issue in your code:

### No function is not exits in Helper class

There no function exits in `Company_Invoices_Helper_Data`  which is  wrong in `oops php`.Without function you can get data from send `this helper class and with sending parameters` to call you `cannot` get order  `getOnestepcheckoutCustomercomment()`

### Wrong  rewrite  class call of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice

As per code you want to rewrite class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` by

`Company_Invoices_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` and it should be `Company_Invoices_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` and

**location** should be `app/code/YourModuleCodePool/Company/Invoices/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`

### May Multiple Module rewrite class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice

As per as your  code , may also  `Webshopapps_Invoicing` module rewrite  class. in this you need follow below link

[How to prevent module rewrite class conflict in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/how-to-prevent-module-rewrite-class-conflict-in-magento)

and [webshopapps](http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2010/11/resolving-magento-extension-conflicts/)

**Most important:** You can get order object from  $order = `$invoiceObject->getOrder();` without  `order object`  you can no`t  get getOnestepcheckoutCustomercomment value`